# Receiving 'NULL' return from OPENJSON() when reading JSON data

Tags: json, sql-server

I need to pull the data from a seperate JSON File into my SQL table however , I cant seem to come right with a result. 
It keeps returning 'NULL' and I dont quite understand why - I suspect it is the JSON path listed in the OPENJSON() but cant seem to come right.

JSON

```
{
    "isMoneyClient": false,
    "showPower": true,
    "removeGamePlay": true,
    "visualTweaks": {
      "0": {
        "value": true,
        "name": "Clock"
      },
      "1": {
        "value": true,
        "name": "CopperIcon"
      }
   }
}
```

SQL

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\config.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS A

UPDATE dbo.CommonBaseline
SET CommonBaseline.Config_isMoneyClient =  isMoneyClient ,
    CommonBaseline.Config_showPower =  showPower , 
    CommonBaseline.Config_removeGamePlay =  removeGamePlay
     FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
        WITH ( 
            isMoneyClient Varchar (50),
            showPower Varchar (50),
            removeGamePlay Varchar (50)
            )
```

AS REQUESTED I HAVE BELOW THE COMMON BASELINE SCHEME

```
CREATE TABLE CommonBaseline (
    ServerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Config_isMoneyClient varchar(255) ,
    Config_showPower varchar(255) ,
    Config_removeGamePlay varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: can you post your `CommonBaseline` schema

Comment: No repro, the code works - it updates *all* rows in the table, assuming there are any. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. You should probably use `INSERT` instead, or add a WHERE clause that identifies the correct row to update

Comment: `OPENJSON` returns one row with your `JSON` example. What does exactly `@JSON` contain after `OPENROWSET()` call (what does `PRINT @JSON` output)?

Comment: @Zhorov It prints out the Content in the JSON File however I see it stops accepting the content after a specific line. 
Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

This is an attempt to improve this answer. When you miss a `column path` definition in `OPENJSON()` call using `WITH` clause, matches between the keys in  `JSON` expression and the column names are **case sensitive**. This is another possible reason for unexpected `NULL` results, because you don't use column paths in your `OPENJSON()` call.

Example:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "isMoneyClient": false,
    "showPower": true,
    "removeGamePlay": true,
    "visualTweaks": {
      "0": {
        "value": true,
        "name": "Clock"
      },
      "1": {
        "value": true,
        "name": "CopperIcon"
      }
   }
}'

-- NULL results. 
-- The column names (IsMoneyClient) and 
-- the keys in JSON expression (isMoneyClient) don't match.
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@json) WITH ( 
   IsMoneyClient Varchar (50),
   ShowPower Varchar (50),
   RemoveGamePlay Varchar (50)
)

-- Expected results. The correct column paths are used
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@json) WITH ( 
   IsMoneyClient Varchar(50) '$.isMoneyClient',
   ShowPower Varchar(50) '$.showPower',
   RemoveGamePlay Varchar(50) '$.removeGamePlay'
)
```

**Original answer:**

One possible explanation for your unexpected result is the fact, that in some cases, even if your `JSON` content is invalid, `OPENJSON()` reads only part of this content. I'm able to reproduce this with the next example:

Statement:

```
-- JSON
-- Valid JSON is '[{"name": "A"},{"name": "B"}]'
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
   {"name": "A"},
   {"name": "B"}
'
-- Read JSON content
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$')
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$') WITH (
   [name] nvarchar(100) '$.name'
)
```

Output (`OPENJSON()` reads only `{"name": "A"}` part of the `JSON` input):

```
----------------
key value   type
----------------
name    A   1

----
name
----
A
```

One solution here is to check your `JSON` content with `ISJSON`:

```
IF ISJSON(@json) = 1 PRINT 'Valid JSON' ELSE PRINT 'Not valid JSON';
```

If it is possible, try to fix the input `JSON`:

Statement:

```
-- JSON
-- Valid JSON is '[{"name": "A"},{"name": "B"}]'
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
   {"name": "A"},
   {"name": "B"}
'
-- Read JSON content    
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', @json, ']'), '$') WITH (
   [name] nvarchar(100) '$.name'
)
```

Output:

```
---- 
name
---- 
A
B
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table schema of `CommonBaseline`. Datatype of columns `Config_isMoneyClient`, `Config_showPower`, `Config_removeGamePlay`

As per below scenario it is working fine

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'e:\config.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS A

or 

SELECT @JSON = '{
"isMoneyClient": false,
"showPower": true,
"removeGamePlay": true,
"visualTweaks": {
  "0": {
    "value": true,
    "name": "Clock"
  },
  "1": {
    "value": true,
    "name": "CopperIcon"
   }
 }
}'

declare @CommonBaseline as Table 
( id int,
Config_isMoneyClient bit,
Config_showPower bit,
Config_removeGamePlay bit )

insert into @CommonBaseline ( id ) values ( 1 )  ---- please check your table CommonBaseline as atleast 1 record to update the same

UPDATE @CommonBaseline 
SET Config_isMoneyClient =  isMoneyClient ,
    Config_showPower =  showPower , 
    Config_removeGamePlay =  removeGamePlay
     FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
        WITH ( 
            isMoneyClient Varchar (50),
            showPower Varchar (50),
            removeGamePlay Varchar (50)
            )
select * from @CommonBaseline
```

Note: Please check you already have your row in `CommonBaseline`. Since you are using `update`.